# saving items in Parse query adapter in main activity to favorites adapter by click

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I want to be able to touch the items in the main activity and once touch the item will save to the favorites class. I'm assuming I need to implement and OnItemClickListener but I am having trouble implementing it correctly. please help
Also do I need to add another intent code and place the onclicklistener inside of there? If more information is needed please let me know, I have been stuck on this issue for awhile now. Thank you

This is my main activity code

```
import com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter;



public class WingmanListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ParseQueryAdapter<Tip> mainAdapter;

    private FavoriteTipAdapter favoritesAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setClickable(true);

        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Tip>(this, Tip.class);
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");
        mainAdapter.setImageKey("photo");

        //Subclass ParseQueryAdapter
        favoritesAdapter = new FavoriteTipAdapter(this);


        //Default view is all wingman tips
        setListAdapter(mainAdapter);

       /* String url = "http://twitter.com/";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url); */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wingman_list, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_refresh: {
                updateTipList();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.action_favorites: {
                showFavorites();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.action_new: {
                newTip();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.twitter: {
                twitter();
                break;
                }
            }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void twitter() {
        Intent a = new Intent(this, Twitter.class);
        startActivityForResult(a, 0);

    }


    private void updateTipList() {
        mainAdapter.loadObjects();
        setListAdapter(mainAdapter);
    }

    private void showFavorites() {
        favoritesAdapter.loadObjects();
        setListAdapter(favoritesAdapter);

    }

    private void newTip() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NewTipActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```